# Django Rest Framework - Search text in all models and fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Now I can search specific fields in my models like http:localhost:8000/user/?username=Myuser, but now I'm looking for a more generic search: I want to search some text and obtain all the coincidences regardless of the model they belong, like http:localhost:8000/search/?"foo"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: write a custom endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [django-haystack](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). It provides you a search engine for your models. It needs some configuration but it works well. After you've configured it, you can create a custom endpoint using its [search views](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html)